# getting cocos2d-html5 to work with visual studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, cocos2d-html5

`<rant>` I swear dealing with IDE problems are the worse.  Its like all I want to do is get my hands dirty with some code but can't. `</rant>`

As the title suggest I am trying to get Cocos2d-HTML5 working in Visual Studio 2012.  I have coppied the Cocos2d-HTML5 files to my web directory and followed a few of the tutorials but am having a problem with `jsloader.js`.

Prior to the change below it was not finding the `jsloader.js` :

```
   FROM:  `engineDir: '../cocos2d/',`
   TO:  `engineDir: '../GridWars/cocos2d/'`
```

`Gridwars` is the name of the project

Now it finds `jsloader.js` but has an error.

```
Unhandled exception at line 117, column 5 in http://localhost:51244/GridWars/cocos2d/platform/jsloader.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'loadExtension' of undefined or null reference
```

for these lines of code:

```
var d = document;
var c = d.ccConfig;

if (c.loadExtension != null && c.loadExtension == true) {
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was posted on their [release notes](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Upgrade_Guide_for_Cocos2d-html5_v21).  I was following one of their tutorials and ended up finding my answer at the bottom of the post.

ANSWER:

in `cocos2d.js`

look for "`s.c = c`",

change it to "`document.ccConfig = c`"

in `main.js`

look for "`config:document.querySelector('#cocos2d-html5')['c'],`"

change it to "`config:document.ccConfig,`"

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Cocos2d-html5 did you used?

It is required to configure your settings in the cocos2d.js file. You may find this file in the template folder.

For example:

```
var c = {

    COCOS2D_DEBUG:2, //0 to turn debug off, 1 for basic debug, and 2 for full debug

    box2d:false,

    chipmunk:false,

    showFPS:true,

    loadExtension:false,    //**Hey, here is the loadExtension.....**

    frameRate:60,

    tag:'gameCanvas', //the dom element to run cocos2d on

    engineDir:'../cocos2d/',

    //SingleEngineFile:'',

    appFiles:[

        'src/resource.js',

        'src/myApp.js'//add your own files in order here

    ]

};
```

Comment: For the most part this is what mine does.  except I needed to change my engine to include the project name so that it looks like this: <project name>/cocos2d/

Comment: you pointed me in the right direction but it was my answer below that fixed it

Answer (score 1):

v2.2 has a similar error. I found that moving a line around in your cocos2d.js file helps.

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    ...
    d.body.appendChild(s);
    document.ccConfig = c;
    s.id = 'cocos2d-html5';
    //else if single file specified, load singlefile
});
```

Remove the line: `document.ccConfig = c;` and move it before the `window.addEventListener`

eg:

```
document.ccConfig = c;

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   // etc
});
```